# how to publish react component library to an npm pacakge without aa.TextEncoder error when using the npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm, nrwl-nx

i've been publishing react component library npm packages (that contain only client side components).

https://github.com/comcast/porrtal

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=%40porrtal

recently, i published a new version of the npm packages after upgrading nx (which upgraded me to react 18).

now when i try to use the npm packages i'm publishing, i get an error about aa.TextEncoder not being a constructor.

When I inspect the esm js in my npm package, i see sections of code brought in from react-dom-server (which is where the aa.TextEncoder reference is)

how do i get the build to exclude the server side react libraries?  (or other way to fix the error?)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.  In https://nx.dev monorepos, where you are creating and publishing react 18+ npm packages with @nx/rollup executor, you need to add "react" and "react-dom" to the `project.json` file's `targets/build/options/external` array.

This lets the bundler know that you are expecting the consumer of the package to supply these packages.  My package's js files no longer contain `aa.TextEncorder` and the consuming app builds and runs.